# Streaming video from Syphon into openCV on python

Tags: python, opencv, syphon

I am trying to get a video feed into openCV on python using Syphon. I'm using Black Syphon to get video in via a Blackmagic Intensity box. Does anyone have any experience with this?

The capture in openCV is really just this, which :

```
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

Is there a way to direct the stream from Syphon into OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear to be possible (without coding beyond my capabilities). The other option is to use openCV within Processing and use the Syphon library.